# Derivative[0, 1, 1][QPolyGamma] cannot be calculated numerically?

Tags: special-functions, numerical-value

During a more complicated calculation, I got an expression

```
 Derivative[0, 1, 1][QPolyGamma][0, 1 + Log[r]/Log[r*s], r*s] /. {r -> 0.21303475787708101008, s -> 2.41291383965919629189}
```

An attempt at a numeric value is returned as unevaluated. Why ?

Of course it is true that

```
  D[D[QPolyGamma[n, z, q], q], z]
  (* Derivative[0, 1, 1][QPolyGamma][n, z, q] *)
```

is the same as

```
  D[D[QPolyGamma[n, z, q], z], q]
  (* Derivative[0, 0, 1][QPolyGamma][1 + n, z, q] *)
```

and this expression can already be calculated numerically:

```
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][QPolyGamma][1, 1 + Log[r]/Log[r*s], r*s] /. {r -> 0.21303475787708101008, s -> 2.41291383965919629189}
 (* 0.42556494660673657 *)
```

According to the known result of a calculation, I verified that this value is correct.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Or is there a subtle mathematical assumption that prevents simplification? `D[QPolyGamma[0, z, q], z, q]` gives `Derivative[0, 0, 1][QPolyGamma][1, z, q]` (pulling the $z$-derivative into the argument $n$) but `D[QPolyGamma[0, z, q], q, z]` gives `Derivative[0, 1, 1][QPolyGamma][0, z, q]` and refuses to do so. In general, `Derivative[0, m, p][QPolyGamma][n, z, q]` should give `Derivative[0, 0, p][QPolyGamma][m + n, z, q]` but it does not.

Comment: Workaround: use a replacement: `Derivative[dn_, dz_, dq_][QPolyGamma][n_, z_, q_] :> Derivative[dn, 0, dq][QPolyGamma][n + dz, z, q]`